# Error when access to Nextcloud in Kubernetes

Tags: nginx, ssl, kubernetes, nextcloud

My goal is :

- create a pod with Nextcloud
- create a service to access this pod
- from another machine with nginx route a CNAME to the service

I tried to deploy a pod with Nextcloud and a service to access it but actually I can't access it. I have an error :

> message ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR.

I just followed a [tutorial](https://www.andremotz.com/nextcloud-docker-on-kubernetes-cluster-ssl-certificates/) at the beginning but I didn't want to use nginx like it was explained because I have it on another machine.

When I look at pods (nextcloud + db) and services they look ok but I have no response when I try to access nextcloud.

[image]
(nc = nextcloud)

[image]

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: nc
  name: nc
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nc
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nc
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: DEBUG
          value: "false"
        - name: NEXTCLOUD_URL
          value: http://test.fr
        - name: NEXTCLOUD_ADMIN_USER
          value: admin
        - name: NEXTCLOUD_ADMIN_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: nextcloud
              key: NEXTCLOUD_ADMIN_PASSWORD
        - name: NEXTCLOUD_UPLOAD_MAX_FILESIZE
          value: 4G
        - name: NEXTCLOUD_MAX_FILE_UPLOADS
          value: "20"
        - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
          value: nextcloud
        - name: MYSQL_HOST
          value: mariadb
        - name: MYSQL_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mariadb
              key: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
        - name: MYSQL_USER
          value: nextcloud
        name: nc
        image: nextcloud
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          protocol: TCP
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/www/html
          name: vnextcloud
          subPath: html
        - mountPath: /var/www/html/custom_apps
          name: vnextcloud
          subPath: apps
        - mountPath: /var/www/html/config
          name: vnextcloud
          subPath: config
        - mountPath: /var/www/html/data
          name: vimages
          subPath: imgnc
        - mountPath: /var/www/html/themes
          name: vnextcloud
          subPath: themes
      restartPolicy: Always
      volumes:
        - name: vnextcloud
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: nfs-pvcnextcloud
        - name: vimages
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: nfs-pvcimages
```

For creating the service I use this command line :

```
kubectl expose deployment nc --type=NodePort --name=svc-nc --port 80
```

And to access my nextcloud I tried the address @IP_MASTER:32500

My questions are:

- **How to check if a pod is working well ?**
  to know if the problem is coming from the service or the pod
- **What should I do to have access to my nextcloud ?**
  I didn't do the tuto part "Create self-signed certificates" because I don't know how to manage. Should it be on my other Linux machine or in my Kubernetes Cluster

Comment: Did you try to port forward to your nextcloud pod? https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** Please consider using stable [nextcloud helm chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/nextcloud)

**2.** This tutorial is a little outdated and can be found also [here](https://github.com/andremotz/nextcloud-kubernetes)

In kubernetes 1.16 release you should change in all your deployments apiVersion to `apiVersion: apps/v1` please take a look at [Deprecations and Removals](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/release/notes/#deprecations-and-removals).
 In addition you should get an error `ValidationError(Deployment.spec): missing required field "selector"` so please add selectors in your deployment under  `Deployment.spec` like:

```
selector:
  matchLabels:
    app: db
```

**3.** Finally Create self-signed certificates. this repo is using   **OMGWTFSSL - [Self Signed SSL Certificate Generator](https://hub.docker.com/r/paulczar/omgwtfssl/)**. Once you provide necessary information like server name, path to your local `hostpath` and names for your SSL certificates it will be automatically created after one pod-run under specified `hostpath`:

```
volumes:
  - name: certs
    hostPath:
      path: "/home/<someFolderLocation>/certs-pv"
```

- those information should be re-used in the section Nginx reverse Proxy for `nginx.conf`

**4.** In your nc-svc.yaml you can change the service type to the **type: NodePort**

**5.** How to verify if your sercie is working properly:

```
kubectl get pods,svc,ep -o wide

Pods:
pod/nc-6d8694659d-5przx   1/1     Running     0          15m   10.244.0.6 
Svc: 
service/svc-nc       NodePort    10.102.90.88   <none>        80:32500/TCP
Endpoints: 
endpoints/svc-nc       10.244.0.6:80
```

You can test your service from inside the cluster running separate pod (f.e. ubuntu)

```
curl your_svc_name
```

you can verify if service discovery is working properly:

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf
nslokup svc_your_svc_name (your_svc_name.default.svc.cluster.local)
```

From outside the cluster using NodePort:

```
curl NODE_IP:NODE_PORT ( if not please verify your firewall rules)
Once you provided hostname for your nextcloud service you should use
curl -vH 'Host:specified_hostname' http://external_ip/ (using http or https according to your configuration)
```

In addition you can exec directly into your db pod

```
kuebctl exec -it db_pod -- /bin/bash  and run 

mysqladmin status -uroot -p$MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD
mysqlshow  -uroot -p$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD --status nextcloud
```

**6.** What should I do to have access to my nextcloud ?
I didn't do the tuto part "Create self-signed certificates" because I don't know how to manage.

**7.** As described under point 3.

**8.** This part is not clear to me: `from another machine with nginx route a CNAME to the service`

Please refer to: 
An [ExternalName Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#externalname) is a special case of Service that does not have selectors and uses DNS names instead.

Additional resources:

- Expose your [Kubernetes service from your own custom domains](https://hackernoon.com/expose-your-kubernetes-service-from-your-own-custom-domains-cc8a1d965fc)
- What’s [the difference between a CNAME and a Web Redirect?](https://totaluptime.com/kb/whats-the-difference-between-a-cname-and-a-web-redirect/)

Hope this help.

Comment: Hello, 
Thank you for your answer. Just to share with you my progress

1. I can't init helm (error : the server could not find the requested resource)
2. 4. 5. done
6. I tried the point 3 but I have plenty of errors. I need to check the volumes.
8. I have a VM with Nginx already and I just didn't want to create another nginx in my VM with kubernetes. I just wanted to make it as simple as possible in kubernetes and add some certificates and security in my other VM. Maybe I missed something in your advices.

Comment: As per helm error - please try this [solution](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/6374#issuecomment-533427268) (the error can be related to the point 2. apiVersion: apps/v1 in tiller deployment). If I understood correctly the last part about nginx - please try to follow steps from this tutorial with service type LoadBalancer. In addition you should apply configuration with sssl certs for your current nginx as descibed [here](https://github.com/andremotz/nextcloud-kubernetes) .

Comment: For helm error I tried what you said and the pod couldn't be created because of another error message "serviceaccount "tiller" not found "
I will try with SSL this weekend

Comment: So please follow [TILLER AND ROLE-BASED ACCESS CONTROL](https://helm.sh/docs/using_helm/#tiller-and-role-based-access-control) fro mthe official docs

Comment: Thank you a lot ! Now helm is working. I will play with the different parameters this evening or tomorrow.